# How can I see when the txt file was embedded to a word document?

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there a possibility to search when the embedded txt file was created in the word document?
I'm working in Word 2010 and the extension of the document is simple: .doc

It was inserted using the Word options:

```
Insert -> Object -> Create from file -> Insert as icon
```

Thank you, I already tried the right click and properties option, but the problem with it, that it shows only the current date for all of the 3 options (created/modified/accessed).

I also tried to get the timestamp but it is inactive when I'm on the txt object.

Sorry not to mention it before: Thank you all of you here for the help and support it is really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SU. It is generally a good idea to put as much detail as you can into your question to help people give a useful answer. In this case, how did you embed the file for example?

Comment: It was by using the Word options Insert -> Object -> Create from file -> Insert as icon.

Comment: For future reference, the details go in the question and the thanks can go in the comments :)  This is to help the questions and answers be useful references over time without being cluttered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: While I will leave the original for reference, it is wrong. The embedded object does not have any meta-data kept with it probably because it is in the old OLE binary format dumped inside the XML.

If you rename the `docx` file to `.zip` & examine the embedded object, the bin file has a default date (1980-01-01).

The only way to get round this would be to write a small helper VBA function to do the embedding for you. You would have to keep track of the objects being embedded and store the meta data in document variables.

---

<strike>If you right click on the resulting icon, you will see an entry called "Packager Shell Object Object" or at least you will in Word 2013, it may be different in other versions.</strike>

Click on "Properties" and you will get a Windows Explorer properties box which will tell you when the object was created.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I already tried this one, but the problem with it, that it shows only the current date for all of the 3 options (created/modified/accessed).

Comment: I also tried to get the timestamp but it is inactive when I'm on the txt object.

Comment: Oops, assumptions will be the death of me! You are correct that all 3 timestamps are the same and are updated when you reopen the document. This is due to embedding being the old fashioned OLE binary format. Sad to say that the information you seek is not stored in the document. See my update.

Comment: See my comment about a possible work around though. If you know VBA or have access to someone who does, the information could easily be tracked.

Comment: Is it works for as a detective check too or can I apply this only for future occasions?

Comment: It would only work for future occasions as the script would be keeping track of the date by saving the current date in a document field when you embedded a file via the script.

Answer (score 0):

Word documents with .docx extension are .zip files, so you can put any file inside. Not sure if Word would see that and complain about it.

Comment: No, you cannot do that I'm afraid, when you try to reopen the document, Word will say it is corrupt. Word keeps track of all of the resources embedded in the zip.